# Pinescript not allowing long and short in backtest, but what about live?

Tags: pine-script

I gather Pinescript doesn't support hedging, i.e. opening a long and short at the same time. But what about if I use AutoView to auto trade the script that I write, will it then stop closing my opposing trades when working on a live chart?

Also is there any way to allow hedging? It seems mad that you can't do this in back testing, its pretty standard!

Answer (score 0):

Allowing trading in both directions (long and short) on the same symbol at the same time is not supported yet. But we have a task on that in our backlog.